# Generate 1000 MHz clock in VHDL from 100 MHz

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

Is it possible to generate a 1000 MHz clock from a 100 MHz in VHDL ?
I want to create a 1ns counter and my fpga has a 100 MHz clock!

Comment: Hi! First of all, have you checked if your component can achieve such high frequency, register to register ?

Comment: Normally, Xilinx FPGAs are limited around 700-800 MHz. Higher frequencies can not be handled by clock buffers, except for I/O clock buffers.

Answer (score 3):

Clock generation is usually done with Phase Locked Loop (PLL) or Digital Clock Manager (DCM), available in the FPGA as dedicated FPGA hardware resources.

If you want to scale up a clock, like going from 100 MHz to 1000 MHz, then you definitely need to use the dedicated FPGA hardware resources in order to get a stable and manageable implementation.

However, a clock of 1000 MHz is very likely too fast for use in any general logic, like a standard counter.  Clocks that fast are typically only used for some very special purposes like internally in a SERDES etc.

So you probably have to consider some different way to implement the required functionality.